# Access get the last ID using OleDbDataReader in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have the following code and it turns out that when trying to find the last data with `OleDbDataReader`, it does not restore the id that belongs to that row, in turn it returns 0.

If it were the **previous** one to the last one and **previous to this one**, then the **id returns perfectly to me**. For example:

```
 id
```

- 1 ---> return
- 2 ---> return
- 3 ---> return
- 4 ---> return
- 5 ---> no return

reference  of the Table Usuario.

```
| Id | ddi   | Name   |
|----|-------|--------|
| 1  | 77652 | Sam    |
| 2  | 76382 | Marts  |
| 3  | 47538 | Irlon  |
| 4  | 83757 | Mayron |
| 5  | 88657 | Peynr  |
```

-

- The **Txddi.Text** = 88657

  -

```vb
Private Function Datos()
    cnn.Close()
    Dim id As Integer
    Dim datas As String
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Id, ddi, Name FROM Usuario WHERE ddi=" & Txddi.Text, cnn)
    cnn.Open()
    Dim search As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If search.Read Then
        id = search("Id")  '------------> doesn't return the last id
        LblName.Text = search("Name")
        LblExist.Text = "Exist"
        Return id
    Else
        Return id
        LblExist.Text = "New"
    End If
    cnn.Close()

End Function
```

> return ->  0

Comment: Check value of`xddi.Text`. What creates the new data? Maybe it is not saved yet. In Access frontend you have a recored selector the shows status. If you fill the first control in new record, the next autoincrement value is displayed, but the record selector shows a pencil, what means new data not saved. If you use undo, the new id disapears.

Comment: First of all, be sure that your query is correct and returns true data. if ddi field is string you have to add ' to your query before and after Txddi.Text

Comment: Hi @ComputerVersteher , I have added a reference image but with respect to the search text I have colored it dark red and if it exists, the code is to search the database.

Comment: **Don't** use images to display data, use [formated](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) text! You have checked`Txddi.Text`? Tables structure? You don't use a form bound to the table and the last value is not just created? Avoid using`Integr`variables, use`Long`!

Comment: @ComputerVersteher I have changed it to Long "id", but still, it returns me 0

Comment: And`Txddi.Text`? `ddi`is a number? Try`SELECT Top 1 Id, ddi, Name FROM Usuario ORDER BY id DESC`as sql statement .

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Yes `Txddi.Text =88657`

Comment: Did you try my query?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Yes, it still does not work but I have managed to make it work with `LIKE` but it will confuse me when I have several ddi with the same user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196011/discussion-between-computerversteher-and-royer).

Answer (score 1):

I am glad you got your code working but I would like to point out a few improvements to the code.

Functions must have a datatype.

Keep your database objects local so you can assure that they are closed and disposed. Using...End Using blocks will do this for you even if there is an error.

You can pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection. Connections are precious resources. Do not open until the last moment and close as soon as posible. In your code the connection is never closed because as soon as the code encounters Return it returns execution to the calling code.

Always use Parameters in sql statements to avoid sql injection and ensure correct datatypes. Access does not care about the names of parameters. What matters is that order the parameters appear in the sql statement must match the order that the parameters are added to the parameters collection. You will need to check the database for the actual datatype of ddi and adjust OleDbType accordingly. Also correct the cast of the text box value if necessary.

Do as little as possible inside the Using blocks. I have assigned the values to the user interface outside the blocks and finally returned the id.

```
Private Function Datos() As Integer
    Dim id As Integer
    Dim name As String = ""
    Dim ExistText = ""
    Using cnn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Id, ddi, Name FROM Usuario WHERE ddi= @ddi;", cnn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ddi", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(Txddi.Text)
            cnn.Open()
            Using search As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                If search.Read Then
                    id = CInt(search("Id"))
                    name = search("Name").ToString
                    ExistText = "Exist"
                Else
                    ExistText = "New"
                End If
            End Using 'closes and disposes reader
        End Using 'closes and disposes command
    End Using 'closes and disposes connection
    LblName.Text = name
    LblExist.Text = ExistText
    Return id
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve it and is adding **`LIKE`** which is used to search for data with the same feature.

`Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Id, ddi, Name FROM Usuario WHERE ddi LIKE '%" + Txddi.Text + "%'", cnn)`